# Как в 1С с помощью метода "НайтиПоРеквизиту" вывести конкретные реквизиты?

Tags: 1с

Есть такой код:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ИскатьСредства()
ИскатьОсновныеСредства = Документы.ИнвентаризацияОС;
Сообщить(ИскатьОсновныеСредства.НайтиПоРеквизиту("ОтветственноеЛицо", Справочники.ФизическиеЛица.НайтиПоНаименованию("Белкина Анна Григорьевна")));  
КонецПроцедуры
```

Выводит такой результат: `Инвентаризация ОС КП00-000001 от 18.09.2022 15:15:19`

Как в 1С с помощью метода "`НайтиПоРеквизиту`" вывести конкретные реквизиты?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод **НайтиПоРеквизиту** возвращает найденный элемент в виде ссылки. Через ссылку можно получить доступ к реквизитам элемента(объекта).

Пример:

```
ДокОснСредства = ИскатьОсновныеСредства.НайтиПоРеквизиту("ОтветственноеЛицо", Справочники.ФизическиеЛица.НайтиПоНаименованию("Белкина Анна Григорьевна"));

Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(ДокОснСредства) Тогда
    ДатаДокумента = ДокОснСредства.Дата;
    НомерДокумента = ДокОсновныеСредства.Номер;
    Организация = ДокОсновныеСредства.Организация;
    ...
КонецЕсли;
```

P.S. Воспользуйтесь точкой остановки и режимом отладки. Это упростит понимание особенности работы с объектами в 1с.